# Regression for multinomial distribution (negative and positive correlation coefficients)

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution

I have a dependent variable, which is a multinomial distribution resulting from positive and negative correlation coefficients. This is a study from the field of [Dendrochronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochronology).

[image: Multinomial distribution]

Those correlation coefficients represent the relationships between tree-growths (i.e. standardized tree-ring widths) and sums of precipitation. For example: 
There is tree-ring width chronology (TRWi from site 1) and there are summer precipitation in mm (for site 1). An example table is below.

[image]

Calculated correlation coefficient is between TRWi and Precipitation variable. Longitude, latitude and altitude are constants for this specific site. Now, there are approximately 1000 different sites and in the first step, correlation coefficients are calculated for each site. At some sites, trees respond positively to higher precipitation sums, while for others this relationship is negative. After 1000 calculations, regression table looks like one below.

[image]

Now, it is time for step 2 and I would like to model this variable as a function of longitudes, latitudes and altitudes.

What model would you suggest?

Comment: Please expand the question to include more detail of where these correlation coefficients came from.

Comment: I added additional information. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't model the ring widths as a response variable, with precipitation, longitude, latitude and altitude as explanatory variables ?

Comment: This is actually very interesting suggestion. If you look more closely, how each correlation coefficient is calculated, you will note that latitudes, longitudes and altitudes are constant values in this equation (see Expanded question).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "constant values". Can you post a link to the actual data ? What is your research question ?

Comment: By constant value I mean, each correlation coefficient is calculated within one site, which has its altitude, longitude and latitude. For this specific side, latitude, altitude and longitude do not change. Of course, they do change between sites. I added an example table to the question. Otherwise, I could prepare a subset of research data, but I believe the problem should be conceptually clearer now. 
My research question: is there an effect of latitude, longitude and altitude on the value of correlation coefficient.

Comment: Have you investigated whether correlation is a good measure of association between width and precipitation for each site ? (ie can you rule out non-linearities?)

Comment: Yes, there are also other methods for estimating the effect of environment on tree-growth, but linear relationship usually works OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your research question *really* is about the correlation coefficients I suppose you could run a linear regression using the correlation coefficients as predicted variable and altitude, longitude and lattitude as explanatory variables.

However, if your main interest lies in how the relation between tree ring width and precipation changes with location and height I think you are better off using a linear model with interaction effects. You are then effectively estimating the equation:

$Width=\beta_0+\beta_1Precipation+\beta_2altitude+\beta_3latitude+\beta_4longitude+\beta_5Precipation*altitude+\beta_6Precipation*latitude+\beta_7Precipation*longitude$

If the relation between amount of rainfall and growth changes with say altitude that would be picked up by $\beta_5$.

Comment: As far as I know bimodality is not an issue for linear regression per se. You want your residuals to be (roughly) normally distributed, not the original variables. In fact if you use linear regression to compare two means (an unusual scenario, but it is possible) you'd expect your outcome variable to be bimodal

Comment: Yes, on reflection I agree! (+1)